# Deploy multiple functions using serverless creating each function with all files in it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am working on serverless. I have created a project using `serverless create`. Then I have added multiple lambda functions to it. Whenever I deploy, every function is having the entire tree structure as

[image]

[image]

which is not my requirement. I used `indivudually: true` under `package`. Still no use. Please help me solve this.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

We have accomplished similar need as follows:
"AWS Lambda Functions Code in Java 8 with Maven as dependency and build tool"

All the functions are defined in single deployment package and at project level all dependencies are controlled through single Maven.

This way, build generates one deployment bundle and same bundle can be used for all Lambda functions for confirmation, with lambda handler set differently for each function.

This has greatly reduced the deployment process.

Comment: Thanks. Having one lambda entry may be a good solution. But, I want separate functions to deal. Please suggest me a solution in that way.

Comment: Hi, What I am suggesting is separate lambda functions/entry points only. Each lambda function is is separate .java file. In my case, I had 5 java classes/files and each of them dedicated to 1 lambda function.